# Errors when using decorators in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've been having issues trying to compile TypeScript to JavaScript when using decorators. The error I get is this:

> app.ts:11:7 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a
> feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the
> 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to
> remove this warning.
>
> ```
> 11 class Person {
>          ~~~~~~
> ```

I've been searching here in StackOverflow for ways to fix it, and also on other websites, and nothing seemed to work for me. Here's what I've already tried:

- I already have `"experimentalDecorators": true` in my *tsconfig.json* file
- I added `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true` in my settings file
- I tried disabling all my VSCode extensions
- I tried restarting VSCode multiple times and opening the project folders in multiple ways

I keep getting this same error anyways. My TypeScript version is `4.1.2`.

Edit: I uploaded my project to google drive at [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xn8X0GXabyDnhOg1ZJ70BUd33f7kTgoK/view).

Comment: Your VS code can use different version of TS. Please double check in right bottom corner of VS code, which version of TS VS code uses

Comment: @captain-yossarian It says `4.0.3`.

Comment: Click on 4.0.3 and select 4.1.2

Comment: @captain-yossarian I don't get that option. I can only select: "Open tsconfig", "Select TypeScript Version ... 4.0.3" and "TypeScript help". The 4.1.2 version is what I got by typing `tsc -v` in the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest one more thing you could try by checking your `tsconfig.json` to see if this does include your source file or not.

I assume your file is located in under: `src/index.ts`, so you might also need to `include` it in the configuration file.

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    // Include your source file as well
    "src"
  ],
}
```

#### In case of running with input file (your own pattern)

In this case `tsc` doesn't allow you to use your own config anymore which is `tsconfig.json` file.

So you need to specify your options via the CLI as following:

```
tsc -w '.\src\app.ts' --experimentalDecorators --target es6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app.ts file is located under the `src` folder. When I compile TypeScript to JavaScript I write `tsc -w .\src\app.ts` in the terminal, is the code you indicated needed if I do this? I uploaded my project to google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xn8X0GXabyDnhOg1ZJ70BUd33f7kTgoK/view?usp=sharing), hopefully it can be useful.

Comment: Nope. If you try to run specific files as argument in CLI, you have to set your own configuration via CLI  as well in this case `--experimentalDecorators`. Otherwise, you just simply run `tsc`

Comment: I'd like to award the bounty to this question (I have 24 hours to do this), even though I still didn't manage to fix my issue. Do you have any other suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? To sum up, if you want to run with your own files by specifying `src\app.ts`, you have to set your own build options `tsc -w .\src\app.ts --experimentalDecorators` (since tsc won't allow you to use your `tsconfig.json` anymore)

Comment: I understand better now. So, now I tried only running "tsc" and it's working! And I didn't change anything in the tsconfig file or in the settings. Is this how it should be?

Comment: You were likely to run with file input option :) Anyway all good for now

Comment: Indeed I tried what I was doing again, by running `tsc -w .\src\app.ts` and it didn't work. I didn't really understand why this happens. Could you explain? :)

Comment: Did you add needed options in your CLI like above example? `tsc -w '.\src\app.ts' --experimentalDecorators --target es6 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226033/discussion-between-enrico-cortinovis-and-tmhao2005).

Answer (score 3):

add setting

```js
{
  ...
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried that too though. For some reason it still does not work!

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode go to `preferences -> settings`, type `javascript` in search settings input and then you will see an option to `Javascript > Implicit Project Config: Experimental Decorators`. Check it and save the settings file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ifxli. I had already checked it. It says `This setting has been deprecated in favor of JS/TS > Implicit Project Config: Experimental Decorators.`. Could this be the issue?